# mkvmerge Backward Spliting not supported why?

Tags: command-line

I tried this:-

`mkvmerge -o new_file.ogg --split parts:0s-104s,+94s-208s,+8s-12s,+312s-410s,+17s-21s 500.ogg`

Thrown this error:

`"The start time must be bigger than or equal to the previous part's end time"`

because 94 I see in code backward splitting point not allowed.

```
if (!requested_split_points.empty() && (start(requested_split_points.back()))) {
    if (frames_fields)
      throw format_x{boost::format(Y("Invalid start frame/field number for '--split' in '--split %1%' (current part: %2%). The start number must be bigger than or equal to the previous part's end number.\n")) % arg % part_spec};
   else
      throw format_x{boost::format(Y("Invalid start time for '--split' in '--split %1%' (current part: %2%). The start time must be bigger than or equal to the previous part's end time.\n")) % arg % part_spec};
}
```

Can you please guide how to split randomly in entire stream. I want to split some portion backward , some upward, anywhere random between stream anytime.

Is it possible?

Comment: The code section you sohw, doesn't throw that error. Have you tried sorting the individual parts chronologically? (`--split parts:-104s-0s,-208s+94s,-12s+8s,-410s+312s,-21s+17s) assuming that negative start times make sense. What does it mean **for you** that the video is split starting e.g. at `-10s`?

Comment: @Anthon Not working `0s-104s` it display as a range and ,+ sign for prefix the start timecode.If i sorting than what about `0s-104s,+94s-208s` ?

Comment: You have to do that in two separate invocations, as `mkverge` is already beyond 94s when it gets to the second split. Write out to different files and combine them afterwards. Reading backwards in a stream is near impossible, but it could have kept some pointers in the file to start working from (every N seconds), or restart from the beginning, it obviously doesn't